# How to draw retina-captured image back to retina and maintain high quality?

Tags: ios, uiimage, retina-display

I have an app that does a screen capture on a retina-iPad (iPad3.)  Or maybe I just do the screen capture with HOME+POWER and get the image that way, it doesn't matter.  In the end, I have a captured image that is 2048x1536 -- that's 1024x768 @2x.

Now I want to display this image -- this 2048x1536 image -- back on the screen and I want to preserve the lovely retina-ness of it.

When I do something like this *(code typed in web browser)*:

```
UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: pathToMyHiresImage];
UIImageView *myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: myImage];
myImageView.frame = screenBounds;  // make it fit
// etc...
```

I end up with a low-rez (jaggy diagonal lines & text) version of the image.

So my question is: what do I have to do in order to display that image back on the screen and get it to display @2x-DPI, so it has that pretty retina-look?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: pathToMyHiresImage];
// *****Added Code*****
myImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:myImage.CGImage scale:2 orientation:myImage.imageOrientation];
// ********************
UIImageView *myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: myImage];
myImageView.frame = screenBounds;  // make it fit
// etc ...
```

Good luck!

**EDIT** (Olie)
Here is the final code, taking DavidH's suggestion into account:

```
UIImage *myImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: path];

if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector: @selector(scale)])
{
    float screenScale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
    if (screenScale > 1.)
    {
        id oldImage = myImage;
        myImage = [[UIImage imageWithCGImage: myImage scale: screenScale orientation: myImage.imageOrientation] retain];
        [oldImage release];
    }
}
```

Comment: Aaaand... that was *exactly* the line of code I needed, thank you very much!  I wish I could accept this answer @2x!  :)

Comment: You should only perform the second line if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]) == 2). I'm really surprised that you had to do this trickery and that UIImage didn't perform out of the box - this is probably a bug in iOS.

Answer (score 1):

This is where Quartz, i.e. the real data, and UIImage, the veneer, collide. So you get a UIImage of what you created. Ask it for the CGImage and then look at that image. The width and height better be 2048x1536 or something is wrong.

Once you can figure out how to get a "real" sized image, you can save that as "foo@2x.png", then resize it by half, and save that as "foo.png".

UIImage makes thing really easy for nobodies, but when you want real control, you have to dive into Quartz and work where the rubber hits the road.

My guess is that you think you got a retina image, but didn't, then when you go to show it its half rez.

Comment: Hmmm, got some code?  The image in question, if I view it via Photos.app, displays the correct size on the screen, and looks retina-y.  It's size is 2048x1536.  If I use code like I posted, it looks all @1x-y.  So the question is: how do I get the retina-y look in MY app?  Thanks!